# How to iterate over a subset of row-aligned pixels

Tags: c++, png, x11

I have a buffer of BGRA data from a PNG that's row-aligned.

```
unsigned int *data_; // bgra buffer described by 
                     // image_.ximage_->width and 
                     // image_.ximage_->height
```

I'm interested in sampling a subimage within the image.  The subimage is defined by an origin and height and width:

```
struct Box {
        unsigned int x_;
        unsigned int y_;
        unsigned int width_;
        unsigned int height_;
};
```

I'm walking the subimage something like this::

```
unsigned int *origin, p;
origin = data_ + ((image_.ximage_->width * box.y_) + box.x_);
for( unsigned int j = 0 ; j < box.height_; ++j )
{
    p = origin + (image_.ximage_->width * j);
    for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < box.width_; ++i )
    {
        p++;
    }
}
```

But instead of walking every pixel in the subimage what I'd like to do is step through every n pixels.  For example, in looking at a 3x3 subimage originating at 0,0 of this 5x5 image, I'd like to walk through every second pixel:

```
X _ X _ _
_ X _ _ _
X _ X _ _
_ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _
```

But I can't think of a good way to do that.  Any thoughts?  It's important that I do this as fast as possible.

Comment: Shouldn't just changing `++i` by `i+=n` be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what's faster or slower without testing, but a flat index would do the trick:

```
for (uint idx = 0; idx<reg.height*reg.width; idx+=step) {
    uint i = idx%reg.height + reg.x, j = idx/reg.width + reg.y;
    img(i,j) = 'X';
}
```

Testable here: https://godbolt.org/z/7jjGWj8rn

Comment: Small correction however, I think it should be ```uint i = idx%reg.width + reg.x, j = idx/reg.width + reg.y;```